# Google Cloud basic authentication: The caller does not have permission

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, authorization, service-accounts, dependabot

I am trying to authorize Dependabot for a private npm package repository stored in the Google Cloud Artifact registry with basic authentication. I created a Service Account and provided repository level read permissions by assigning the [Artifact Registry Reader](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles) role.

The `.github/dependabot.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: 2
registries:
  my-reg:
    type: npm-registry
    url: <my repo url>
    username: "_json_key_base64"
    password: "${{ secrets.KEY_BASE64}}"

updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    registries:
      - my-reg
[...]
```

where `secrets.KEY_BASE64` is the base64 encoded service account key stored as a Dependabot Secret in GitHub (following [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/configuring-access-to-private-registries-for-dependabot#storing-credentials-for-dependabot-to-use)).
I got some information about the authentication process from this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75608265/23422825) and [this docker KEY_TYPE example](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#json-key).

I also tried this without the base64 encoding (`username: "_json_key"`) but the error is still the same: `{"error":"The caller does not have permission."}`.

When I use a temporary token instead of the permanent secret key it works until the token expires:

```yaml
[...]
  my-reg:
    type: npm-registry
    url: <my repo url>
    token: <my temp token>
[...]
```

When trying to access it with curl I noticed a similar behaviour. When a token is generated it works:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" <url>
```

but if I try using basic auth:

```
curl -u _json_key:<unencoded_secret_key> <url>
```

or with base64 encoding:

```
curl -u _json_key_base64:<encoded_secret_key> <url>
```

it does not work and results in the error: `{"error":"The caller does not have permission."}`. In both cases I removed all whitespace characters from the service account key.

Even with a `.npmrc` inside the root of the repository (where `package.json` is located), like mentioned [here in the dependabot documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/guidance-for-the-configuration-of-private-registries-for-dependabot#:%7E:text=The%20npm%20ecosystem%20requires%20a%20.npmrc%20file%20with%20the%20private%20registry%20URL%20to%20be%20checked%20into%20the%20repository.), it still does not work:

```
@my-reg:registry=<url>
```

I tried using a temporary token (works, but unwanted since the token is temporary).
I tried using `_json_key` username with the unendcoded service account key (does not work).
I tried using `_json_key_base64` username with the base64 encoded service account key (does not work).
I tried adding the above `.npmrc` file (does not work).

How can I provide a permanent solution for the Dependabot to authenticate to out private npm registry?